# C# Generic contains Generic

Tags: c#, generics

Is a way to change where constraint for generic class containing generic member to avoid constructions like this:

```
var _queue = new CommunicationQueue<DataTag<Messages>, Messages>(10);
//this is what I would like:
//var _queue = new CommunicationQueue<DataTag<Messages>>(10);

public class CommunicationQueue<TU, T> where TU : DataTag<T>, new()
                                       where T : struct
{
   private readonly ConcurrentQueue<TU> _queue;
   public int Limit { get; }

   public CommunicationQueue(int queueSize)
   {
       Limit = queueSize;
       _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<TU>();
   }

   internal void AddItem(T item)
   {
      _queue.Enqueue(new TU { RowData = item });
       while (_queue.Count > Limit)
       {
          TU removed;
          _queue.TryDequeue(out removed);
       }
   }

   public IEnumerable<TU> GetLatestItems()
   {
      return _queue.Reverse().Take(Limit).ToArray();
   }
}

 public class DataTag<T> where T : struct 
 {
     public DateTime Time { get; set; }   

     public T RowData { get; set;}

     public DataTag()
     {
         Time = DateTime.Now;
     }

     public DataTag(T rowData) : this()
     {
         RowData = rowData;
     }
 }

public struct Messages
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now to create a queue I should write:

```
var _queue = new CommunicationQueue<DataTag<Messages>, Messages>(10);
```

But this is what I would like:

```
var _queue = new CommunicationQueue<DataTag<Messages>>(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, are you planning to inherit from `DataTag<T>`?

If not, then you could change the definition of `CommunicationQueue` to

```
public class CommunicationQueue<T> 
    where T : struct
{
   private readonly ConcurrentQueue<DataTag<T>> _queue;
//....
}
```

Comment: Then you can create a queue this way: `var _queue2 = new CommunicationQueue<Messages>(10);`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was already thinking about this solution but it's not exactly what I would like. 
It's easy to read - that's fine, but on first sights it look like CommunicationQueue is based on T (message) not on DataTag<T>. And to be true I don't know if inheritance will be required.